# C# webform data insert into database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I use visual studio express and have a online mssql database, i have a webform and must this data into mssql, how is this possible, i can't found any solution, is this to do in default.aspx.cs? I Know how is this to do in php but this is now specific in asp.net c#

Comment: Did you do any research at all about this? There are thousands of tutorials online for webforms.

Comment: that is not a question, who tried to make regarding this?

Comment: And what will be a question please?

Answer (score 1):

Well, consume an event on the web form -like a button click -and use code **like this:**

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("{ConnectionString}"))
{
    c.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table (...) VALUES (@field1, @field2, ...)"))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", someTextBox.Text);
        ...

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Now, you're going to have to take that code and do something with it because your question is missing extensive information -but you can plug it in.

Comment: This was a great help for me, thanke you